# Comment form and comment is not displaying on node

Tags: drupal, comments

Drupal 7.22 comment problem on node

I have one content type basic page with comment open. Now created one view of type basic page and selected display format unformatted list and 'show' content => full content with comment.
When I opend view page everything is fine, I am able to see page content witht comment and comment form but when I open my original node here comment form and comment are not showing.

One more suggestion I want from you all genious people when anyone comment to my view result page it redirect to node/nid#comment/..... link I want it on same page with newly added comment.

It will be very helpful for me please help me.
Thanks

Comment: May be comment closed for that particular node. So go to edit node and check comment status.

Comment: thanks for reply but Problem is global for every content type not for a aprticular node

Comment: Do you use custom templates? Maybe in the node template there are no comments.